# Avoiding implicit conversion in constructor. The 'explicit' keyword doesn't help here

Tags: c++, c++11

I am able to avoid the implicit conversion of a constructor using the `explicit` keyword. So now, conversions like `A a1 = 10;` can be avoided.

But still I can initialize `A a1 = A(20.2);`. How can I disable the object creation such that an object can only be created if we pass an integer as a parameter e.g. `A a1 = A(10)`?

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
public:
    explicit A(int a)
    {
        num = a;
    }

    int num;
};

int main()
{
    A a1 = A(10.0);
    std::cout << a1.num;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 75):

You can `delete` `A::A(<anything not an int>);`:

```
struct A
{
    explicit A(int a)
    : num(a)
    {}

    template<class T>
    A(T) = delete;

    int num;
};

int main()
{
    //A a1=A(10.0); // error: use of deleted function 'A::A(T) [with T = double]'
    A a2 = A(10); // OK
    (void) a2;
}
```

Demo: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/425afc19003697c9

Comment: @Alexander C++ is one of the oldest high level languages that still sees active use in new projects. The only languages that are older and still actively used AFAIK are FORTRAN, COBOL and LISP. A consequence of that is that C++ has A LOT more flexibility than younger languages like Java or C#, but that flexibility comes at the cost of being a lot easier to screw something up.

Comment: @Nzall Flexibility is fine, but implicit-conversion-by-default sounds crazy to me. I haven't used C# much, but I know that it has implicit conversion operators, but they're not the default, and require explicit opt-in (unlike here, where `explicit` has to be explicitly stated to opt-out of implicit behaviour). Along these lines, I also *really* wished `const` was the default. The compiler can catch a non-const reference to a const variable, and require you to write `mutating` (or something to that effect). But it never suggested "this can (should?) be const, btw", in any compiler/IDE i've seen

Comment: @Alexander _"implicit-conversion-by-default sounds crazy to me"_ It sounds crazy to all C++ developpers. But the choice to do so has been made eons ago and we're now all paying the price.

Comment: @YSC Oh, okay, that's kind of relieving to hear, actually. I thought I was taking crazy pills. Was it ever considered to make source-breaking changes, enabled by a compiler flag, macro at the top of the file, etc.? `__EXLICIT_OPERATORS_BY_DEFAULT` or something

Comment: @Nzall Are you suggesting that C is not used much in new projects? Or that it's not a high level language?

Comment: @Barmar Oh right, I forgot about C. Still, C and C++ are very similar and can pretty much be considered together when talking about this. I'm not saying they're interchangeable, but considering Alexander is talking about C++ having sharp edges, I kept C out of it because from what I understand, C++ is considered a cotton swab compared to C in that respect.

Comment: @Nzall I've been programming for over 40 years, I'm proficient in about a half dozen languages and familiar with many more. Modern C++ seems to be in a class by itself in terms of complexity (I remember thinking similarly about Ada when it first came out, but C++ far eclipses that). But I guess that's a testament to its popularity -- they wouldn't keep adding on to it if no one cared.

Comment: @Nzall C is so, soo much simpler than C++, it's not even in the same league. C as a language is one of the simplest ones around (there just isn't much to it), C++ is most certainly the most complicated one of the mainstream languages.

Comment: @Barmar Quite literally; template syntax *on its own* is Turing-complete. The C++ *parser* is subject to the halting problem.

Answer (score 31):

The way to achieve this is to provide another constructor that would be a better match, and then `delete` it so you'll get an error.  For your class, adding

```
template <typename T>
A(T) = delete;
```

Will stop the class from being constructed from anything that isn't an `int`

Answer (score 8):

You can circumvent this problem by using braced initialization. For example:

```
struct A {
  A(int _a) : a(_a) {}
  int a;
};

A a{5}; // ok
A b{1.123}; // compile error
```

[Proof](https://godbolt.org/z/TjDQHH)

Answer (score 6):

I just want to add that the `A(double) = delete` is a `C++11` addition.

If for whatever reason you cannot use this relatively new construct, you can simply declare it as private as this:

```
class A{
  public:
    A(int);
  private:
    A(double);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

To avoid int->double conversions everywhere, not only in your case. With g++ you can use `-Wconversion -Werror`. Note that it'll be allowed in your particular case, because the compiler understands that 10.0 is literal, but it will fail compilation for:

```
class A
{
public:
    explicit A(int a)
    {
        num = a;
    }

    int num;
};

int main()
{
    double x = 10;
    A a1 = A(x);
    static_cast<void>(a1);
    return 0;
}
```

[Compiler explorer](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/L7547n)

Answer (score 4):

Explicitly delete the constructor for `double` (possibly add `float`):

```
A(double) = delete;
```

Answer (score 4):

You should use the -Wconversion flag of gcc, that will generate a warning when implicitly casting a float to an int.
Add -Werror to transform this warning (all in fact) into an error.